# How can I secure user submitted HTML markup?

Tags: html, security

Before I start I'd like to say I have read similar questions here but I don't think it really answers the question: [Show HTML user input, security issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12406590/show-html-user-input-security-issue) and [Security risks from user-submitted HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7540700/security-risks-from-user-submitted-html)

I think these highlight the problems quite well but I am essentially asking advice for best practice in these circumstances.

I have been programming for a while and have just now come to the point where I want website administrators to submit HTML markup to display the content they want in their own sites.

Securing this content in the database is fine but now I want to display it on the site securely.

Even though, this feature is only available to the site admins I still want to secure against malicious script injections and try to prevent them breaking the page by using poor HTML.

Is the reality that I cannot safely guard against script injections as the threads above seemed to point out?

Do I use the mentality that if they break the site, it's down to them, or can I use some sort of markup validator when they update the content?

Comment: what language are you coding? what possible script injections are you talking about? do you want to allow html but forbid javascript? can you give examples?

Comment: You could just whitelist certain html tags, depending on what content theyre uploading.  Like for instance just allow <p><h1><h2><h3><br><img><div>   I believe TinyMCE has this built in...but thats only client side....you should still check and sanitize server side

Answer (score 1):

What do you think about [markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/)?

It's a safe way to submit html, and have libraries to most popular languages.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct, if you allow to submit pure HTML - there's no way to prevent all possible injections. Even if you disable `<script>` tag in all it's possible combinations (and there're many) there're other ways like `onfocus` `onmouseover` events that can be used to run malicious code.

Answer (score 0):

I would advice HTMLPurifier, it's the best solution out there for sure. Google it!