# retain <map> tag in ckeditor

Tags: ckeditor, config

I have seen https://stackoverflow.com/a/21276169/848513

But I can't figure out how to set the ACF to allow for images maps.

The code I have is:

```
<img alt="Map" src="sample.jpg" useMap=#Map border=0>

<map name="Map">
  <area shape="rect" coords="118,32,234,127" href="article.php?id=155" target="list" alt="North">
  <area shape="rect" coords="179,136,299,191" href="article.php?id=156" target="list" alt="East">
  <area shape="rect" coords="17,141,113,223" href="article.php?id=157" target="list" alt="Central">
</map>
```

When i use the following code in the `config.js` file:
`config.allowedContent = 'map area';` - what I get in the editor after pasting that is:

`<p><map><area /> <area /> <area /> <area /></map></p>`

Can someone help we with the exact code i need allow image maps?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Giammin's answer is almost correct, the problem is that it uses the [config.allowedContent](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-allowedContent) option and not the more appropriate [config.extraAllowedContent](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-extraAllowedContent) option which basically **overwrites** your content filter setting instead of **extending** it.

As a result, this turns ACF into the [custom mode](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/acfcustom.html) instead of adjusting the [automatic mode](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/acf.html).

So try the following:

```
config.extraAllowedContent = 
    'area[!shape,!coords,!href,!target,alt];' +
    'map[!name];';
```

Answer (score 1):

ACF is doing exactly what you said to it:
**only allow map and area tag but not any of their attribute.**

you need to specify allowed attributes:

```
config.allowedContent = 
    'area[!shape,!coords,!href,!target,alt];' +
    'map[!name];';
```

Read carefully the documentation:

[Allowed Content Rules](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_allowed_content_rules)

[Advanced Content Filter](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter)

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. It seemed to work, but it also seemed to cancel out ALL other formatting options (including filtering out the image, which is the basis for the image map). Such that the code provided did not ADD the functionality of `map` and `area` - it seemed to limit the editor to solely those tags. Sample of what the editor now looks like: http://i.stack.imgur.com/snOPQ.jpg
 Maybe this is what you meant, but its not what i need. i need the full previous functionality *PLUS* `area + map`

Comment: @kneidels yes, of course! you have to specify every tag/attribute you want to allow. I thought you wanted only those tags

Comment: You have to specify every tag you want to allow only if you want to configure ACF manually. In most cases it is enough to use the automatic mode with default configuration extended by config.extraAllowedContent to accept additional tags. There is no need to write the entire ACF config by yourself.